# AWS Lambda to consume messages from SQS in a different region

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a use-case where my SQS messages are present in us-east region. I wanted to create a lambda in a different region(region with no other lambda) so as to achieve maximum cuncurrency. Is it possible for the lambda to read from other regions? If yes, can anyone guide me with the process?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you just have to provide the correct access. The queue arn/url (depending which you use) specifies the region in it, so as long as your Lambda has access, it will work.

However, it's worth noting that **Lambda concurrency account limit is a soft limit** and you can easily request an increase from AWS support ([read more here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_lambda))

Answer (score 0):

**While you definitely can [1], you shouldn't do this [2,3] for your normal use case**

1. Queue identifiers include the region in them - you can access them from anywhere in the world with the correct permissions.
2. Data transfer out of an AWS region comes with costs: (a) increased latency, and (b) money. Not sure which is more important to you, but they're costs people often miss when setting up cross-region workflows.
3. Most AWS limits can be increased. [Open a support case](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/v1#/case/create?issueType=service-limit-increase) for a limit increase and describe your use case.

   - The limits are put in place partly for protection & partly for AWS to understand use cases where people want to go beyond them, and help those customers use the services in a more optimal manner.

That said, it is supported [1], and can prove useful in emergency situations (like region-specific outages), keeping in mind it will cost a lot more [2].

Comment: Today the AWS Lambda service went offline in a region, but the SQS service did not. Reading SQS messages from lambda functions in another region was the only option for us not to go offline.

Comment: @marciel.deg - Good point. I've updated the answer to take that into consideration. This is useful for emergency situations, but still not a recommended pattern for default use cases due to the higher cost.